# What is it called when the vocals follow the instruments' tempo?

Tags: voice, terminology

Sorry, I don't know how to explain properly.
It's about the vocals and instruments doing same timing.

Here is an example:

and another one:

Answer (score 2):

The general term for instruments and voices playing the same melody (rhythm and pitch) is [unison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unison), but it covers more than your cases: also when two instruments play the same melody or a choir singing the same melody. I'm not sure if there is a more specific (well-known) term which excludes those cases.

If only the rhythm is identical but not the pitch, it might be described as [homorhythm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homorhythm) or homometer, but again that is more often used for multiple *voices*.